# Hooks not triggering when inserting raw queries via sequelize.query()

Tags: mysql, node.js, sequelize.js

I have the following `Employee` model for a MySQL database:

```
var bcrypt = require('bcrypt');

module.exports = (sequelize, DataTypes) => {
    const Employee = sequelize.define(
        "Employee",
        {
            username: DataTypes.STRING,
            password: DataTypes.STRING,
        }, {}
    );
    return Employee;
};
```

Seeding the database is done by reading a `.sql` file containing 10,000+ employees via [raw queries](http://docs.sequelizejs.com/manual/tutorial/raw-queries.html#raw-queries):

`sequelize.query(mySeedingSqlFileHere);`

The problem is that the passwords in the SQL file are plain text and I'd like to use [`bcrypt`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/bcrypt) to hash them before inserting into the database. I've never done bulk inserts before so I was looking into [Sequelize docs for adding a hook to the `Employee` model](http://docs.sequelizejs.com/manual/tutorial/hooks.html#model-hooks), like so:

```
hooks: {
  beforeBulkCreate: (employees, options) => {
    for (employee in employees) {
      if (employee.password) {
        employee.password = await bcrypt.hash(employee.password, 10);
      }
     }
  }
}
```

This isn't working as I'm still getting the plain text values after reseeding - should I be looking into another way? I was looking into [sequelize capitalize name before saving in database - instance hook](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50764922/sequelize-capitalize-name-before-saving-in-database-instance-hook)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Your hooks won't be called until you use model's function for DB operation , so if you are running raw query , hooks will never be fired,**

> **Reason :** You can write anything inside your raw query , select/insert/update/delete anything , how does sequelize.js know that
>   it has to fire the hooks. This is only possible when you use methods
>   like
>
> ```
> Model.create();
> Model.bulkCreate();
> Model.update();
> Model.destroy;
> ```
>
> And as per **[DOC](http://docs.sequelizejs.com/class/lib/sequelize.js~Sequelize.html#instance-method-query)** raw query doesn't have hooks option to add.
>   And for **[MODEL](http://docs.sequelizejs.com/class/lib/model.js~Model.html)** queries you can check that it has option to
>   enable/disable hook.

Comment: Upvoted but what are the workarounds for this ? Let's say sequelize cannot perform what I want through model (i.e. non raw) sql queries (for example : an upsert operation, https://github.com/sequelize/sequelize/issues/11656) , there's no way to use an afterSave hook after a raw query that does this ? That seems restrictive. :( Let's say I have complex code being re-used through hooks across all our projects, I don't want to duplicate this code elsewhere and not use hooks. :(

Comment: Perhaps specifying the queryType (https://sequelize.org/api/v6/class/src/sequelize.js~sequelize#instance-method-query) would help in ensuring those hooks are working properly.