# Is there any Sequelize global hook called after raw query returns records?

Tags: sequelize.js

afterFind hook is not getting called.

Is there any other hook called after raw select query ?

and for update / insert query returning * ?

Comment: Does https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53386132/hooks-not-triggering-when-inserting-raw-queries-via-sequelize-query answer your question?

Comment: Nope. I use Model.findAll() or Model.upsert / create functions...  and wanting the afterFind or any other hook to be called after fetching records.